# Prove that this integral operator is compact

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $X,Y=L^2(0,1)$, $k\in C^0([0,1]^2)$. Define
$$
K:X\to Y,\,\,\,\,\,Kf(x):=\int_0^1k(x,y)f(y)dy\,\,\,\,\forall\, f\in L^2(0,1).
$$
I have to show that $K$ is compact.

My idea is to prove that $K$ is the limit of finite-rank operators. But I don't know exactly which kind of operators should I have to consider.

Comment: Your integral operator is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator, which gives compactness. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_integral_operator

Comment: The exercise is to prove it...

Comment: If you know about Hilbert-Schmidt operators, then all you have to do is note that $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}|k(x,y)|^{2}\,dx\,dy < \infty$. Do you know about such operators?

Comment: The problem is that we didn't deal about them in class

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To show that $K$ is compact using elementary arguments, let $\{ f_{n} \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a bounded sequence in $L^{2}[0,1]$ with $\|f_{n}\| \le M$. For every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|k(x,y)-k(x',y')| < \epsilon$ whenever $|x-x'|+|y-y'| < \delta$. Therefore, $\{ Kf_{n}\}$ is a sequence of continuous functions for which
$$
      |Kf_{n}(x)-Kf_{n}(x')| \le \int_{0}^{1}|k(x,y)-k(x',y)||f_{n}(y)|\,dy \\
               \le \epsilon \int_{0}^{1}|f_{n}(y)|\,dy \le \epsilon\|1\|\|f_{n}\|
                   \le M\epsilon,\;\;\; |x-x'| < \delta.
$$
That shows that $\{ Kf_{n} \}$ is an equicontinuous family of continuous functions on $[0,1]$. So, there exists a subsequence $\{ Kf_{n_{k}}\}$ that converges uniformly to a continuous function $g$. Since uniform convergence implies convergence in $L^{2}[0,1]$, it follows that $\{ Kf_{n_{k}}\}$ converges in $L^{2}[0,1]$. Therefore $K$ is compact because the image of a bounded sequence always contains a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Why "Therefore,$ \{Kf_{n}\}$ is a sequence of continuous functions for which ......"?

Comment: Why you used that the operator $K$ is continuous ?

Comment: what do you mean by "an equicontinuous family "?

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzelà–Ascoli_theorem  in the first section "Statement and first consequences." Equicontinuity is described there.

Comment: Is it the operator $K$ inside the integral $\int_0^1$ or the kernel $k(x,y)$?

Comment: @blux : I corrected the typos, though the context made it clear how it was being used.

Comment: @Intuition To your first question, you just use the Hölder’s inequality and the fact that $[0,1]$ is of finite measure and $f\in L^2[0,1]$.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Hi, if we reduce the condition posted on $k$ to $k\in L^1[0,1]$, can we modify the proof slightly so that it still works?

Comment: @KitWong : The operator norm of $K$ is bounded by the $L^1$ norm of $k$. So you can approximate $K$ in the operator norm by a kernel operator with continuous symbol $k$, and that operator is compact. The compact operators is a norm closed set.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Thanks, though I have not learned the knowledge of kernel operator & continuous symbol. I will review this answer if I learn the knowledge you used.

Answer (score 7):

Using Stone-Weierstass theorem, the function $k$ can be approximated uniformly in $[0,1]^2$ by linear combinations of functions of the form $(x,y)\mapsto u(x)v(y)$, where $u,v\colon [0,1]\to \mathbb R$ are continuous functions.

For such functions, the kernel operator has a finite rank. It remains to show that uniform convergence of the kernel implies convergence for the operator norm.

Comment: Why does Stone-Weierstrass thm implies that fact? Then, I know that I have to write the approximating operators in the form $K_nf(x):=\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i\langle f, u_i\rangle v_i$, where $(u_i)_i$ and $(v_i)_i$ are orthonormal basis of $L^2$. Which are the orthonormal basis in your example?

Comment: We use the theorem with the algebra generated by the functions of the form $(x,y)\mapsto u(x)v(y)$ (it satisfies the assumptions of the theorem).

Comment: What about how to prove that the approximating operators are of the form of my previous comment?

Answer (score 6):

Actually, if $k\in L^2(0,1)^2$, then you may consider $K$ as a limit of a sequence of finite rank operators. Since $L^2(0,1)$ is a separable Hilbert space, there exists a Hilbert basis denoted by $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$. Define $T_n (n\in\mathbb{N}^{+})$ as
$$
T_nf:=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\langle f, e_i \rangle e_i,\quad \forall f\in L^{2}(0,1).
$$ 
Then, $K_n:=T_nKT_n$ is a finite rank operator. And $K_n$ is compact for each $n$. You need to show that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}||K_n-K||=0$. Then, you conclude that $K$ is compact, since the space of compact operators mapping $L^2(0,1)$ into $L^2(0,1)$ is closed.