# If $V\subset L^\infty[0,1]$ with $\|f\|_\infty \leq c\|f\|_2$, then $V$ is finite dimensional

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

If $V$ is a linear subspace of $L^\infty[0,1]$ with $\|f\|_\infty \leq c\|f\|_2$ for all $f\in V$, then $V$ is finite dimensional. The proof is an explicit calculation:

Since $L^\infty[0,1] \subset L^2[0,1]$, take $e_1,\cdots , e_n$ to be $L^2$-orthonormal vectors in $V$. Fix some $x$ in $[0,1]$. We have, for all $y\in[0,1]$,
$$\left|\sum e_i(x)e_i(y)\right| \leq \left\|\sum e_i(x) e_i(\cdot) \right\|_\infty \leq c\left\|\sum e_i(x)e_i(\cdot)\right\|_2 = c \sqrt{ \sum e_i^2(x)},$$
take $y = x$ this implies 
$$\sum e_i^2(x) \leq c^2.$$
Integrate both side and we get
$$  n=\int_0^1 \sum e_i^2(x) \leq c^2.$$
This proof is simple but it is not really intuitive for me. Could you guys help me with a more functional analysis argument of this?

Since for functions in $L^\infty[0,1]$ we always have $\|f\|_2 \leq  \|f\|_\infty$ , paired with $\|f\|_\infty \leq c \|f\|_2$, this means that the identity map is a continuous bijection between $(V, \|\cdot \|_2)$ and $(V, \|\cdot \|_\infty)$. Also $\|\cdot\|_2$ and $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ are equivalent on $V$. I know any two norms are equivalent in a finite dimensional space, but I dont know if there is anything special about the $L^2$ and $L^\infty$ norm to make the converse of that true as well.

Comment: You should say $V$ is a linear subspace. Also, your first inequality needs absolute values on the left.

Comment: Apart from tweaks noted by @zhw., that argument is correct... and does not have analogues in earlier or logically prior ideas, apparently! It is my impression that we should credit A. Grothendieck for this sort of result, in his work in the early 1950s. In particular, this sort of thing is simply a new idea, so maybe does not have obvious more-general analogues... That is, it is not "abstract" functional analysis, but does refer to topological vector spaces of functions on nice physical spaces.

Comment: Here is a Grothendieck reference: http://cms.math.ca/cjm/a144785 (open access). He proved: if $V$ is a subspace of $L^\infty$ that is closed in $L^2$, then it is finite-dimensional. The proof is more functional analysis-oriented.

Comment: @daw: That Grothendieck reference seems to be a broken link. If you can, would you like to fix it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro this is the full reference: 
Grothendieck, A. (1954). Sur Certains Sous-Espaces Vectoriels De Lp. Canadian Journal of Mathematics, 6, 158-160. https://doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1954-017-x

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following functional-analytic proof is an application of the Riesz lemma: a normed space is finite-dimensional if and only if its unit ball is compact, or equivalently, if the identity operator is compact.

The following statement is what we want to prove.

**Proposition**. Let $V$ be a vector space of bounded functions on $[0, 1]$ such that there is $c>0$ satisfying $\lVert f\rVert_{\infty}\le c\lVert f\rVert_2$ for all $f\in V$. Then $V$ is finite-dimensional.

*Remark*. Notice how we are avoiding the mention of $L^\infty([0, 1])$. The reason is that $V$ is a space of functions, whereas $L^\infty$ is typically defined as a space of *equivalence classes* of functions, up to almost everywhere equivalence.

*Proof*. For $x\in [0, 1]$ and $f\in V$ define the evaluation functional $\mathrm{ev}_x(f):=f(x).$ (Note: this would not be well-defined on $L^\infty([0, 1])$, as mentioned in the remark). The assumption implies that this is a bounded linear functional in the $L^2$ topology. So the Riesz representation theorem yields the existence of $K_x\in L^2([0, 1])$ such that
$$
\mathrm{ev}_x(f)=\langle K_x | f \rangle_{L^2([0,1])}=\int_0^1 K(x, y) f(y)\, dy, $$
where we have let $K(x, \cdot):=K_x$.

By assumption,
$$
\lvert \langle K_x | f \rangle_{L^2([0,1])} \rvert \le c \lVert f\rVert_{L^2([0,1])}$$
for arbitrary $f$. Letting $f=K_x$ we see that $\lVert K_x\rVert_2\le c$. The constant on the right-hand side is independent on $x$, so integrating we get $\int_{[0, 1]^2} K(x, y)^2\, dxdy\le c^2$ and we conclude that, in particular, $K\in L^2([0, 1]^2)$.

Now consider $T_K(g):=\int_0^1 K(\cdot, y)g(y)\, dy$, seen as a linear operator of $L^2([0, 1])$ into itself. A consequence of $K\in L^2([0, 1]^2)$ is that [this operator is compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2962909/8157). We infer that the identity operator on $V$ is compact in the $L^2$ topology. By the Riesz lemma we conclude that $V$ is finite-dimensional. $\Box$

*Concluding remarks*.

1. The proof of Grothendieck, given in the main question, is superior to this one for two reasons. First, it is more elementary, and second, it gives an explicit bound on the dimension of $V$ in terms of $c$.
2. The function $K$ is known as a [reproducing kernel](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2962909/8157). A posteriori, given a basis $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ of $V$ that is $L^2$-orthonormal, we have that $K(x, y)=\sum_j e_j(x)e_j(y)$. The function on the right is exactly the one appearing in Grothendieck's proof.

Comment: Why do you ahve $\lVert K_x\rVert_2\le c$ ? Is it a consequence of the assumption $\lVert f\rVert_{\infty}\le c\lVert f\rVert_2$ ?

Comment: @StratosFair: Yes. I edited the text to explain that.

Comment: Oh that's perfectly clear now. Thanks !

Comment: @OliverDíaz: voted to undelete

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: Thanks very much. thus types of questions are the reason I'm still around...