# Are $L^2$-closed subspaces of $C^\infty$ finite-dimensional?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, global-analysis

I have the following question:
Given a closed Riemannian manifold $M$, let $V\subseteq C^\infty(M)$ be a linear subspace that is closed with respect to the $L^2$-norm.
The question now is whether $V$ is finite-dimensional.

My idea is to use Rellich's embedding theorem together with the open mapping theorem:

Denote by $\iota : H^m(M) \rightarrow L^2(M)$, $m \in \mathbb{N}$ the canonical inclusion, by Rellich this is a compact injective map. The restriction of $\iota$ to $V$ gives a bijection $\iota\lvert_V: (V, \lvert\lvert\cdot\rvert \rvert_{H^m})\rightarrow (V,  \lvert\lvert\cdot\rvert \rvert_{L^2})$. If I now can show that $V$ is also closed with respect to the $H^m$-norm, I can use the open mapping theorem to get that the inverse $(\iota\lvert_V)^{-1}:(V,  \lvert\lvert\cdot\rvert \rvert_{L^2})\rightarrow (V, \lvert\lvert\cdot\rvert \rvert_{H^m})$ is continous. In this case, the identity of $V$ factors through $H^m$, i.e. $id_V = \iota\lvert_V \circ (\iota\lvert_V)^{-1}$ and hence it is a compact map. This then implies that $V$ is finite-dimensional.

The missing puzzle piece is therefore to show that $V$ is closed as a subspace of $H^m$ (doesn't matter for which $m$).

I'm grateful for any hint on how to prove this, less grateful for a counterexample, but at least then I can stop thinking about this ;)

Thanks!

Comment: Closed as a subspace of $L^2$ or closed in the subspace topology of $C^\infty$?

Comment: I don't know too much about Riemannina manifolds, but would you be okay with $M = [-1, 1]$? Then $V := \left \lbrace u \in C^\infty([-1, 1]): \int_{\mathbb{R}} u = 0\right \rbrace$ is $L^2$-closed and $x, x^3, x^5, ...$ are all in $V$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4432202/8157) is related, hope it helps.

Comment: @Meowdog $M=[-1,1]$ is not a closed manifold, since it has the boundary points $-1$ and $1$. However I don't think that the vector space you gave me there is L^2-closed, the closure is $\bar{V}=\{u\in L^2([-1,1]) : \int_{-1}^1 u =0\}$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Closed as a subspace of L^2

Comment: @pizzalberto Fair enough

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved it myself, it was actually right before my eyes:

Let $(u_n)\subseteq V$ be a sequence converging in $H^m(M)$, let $u$ be the limit in $H^m(M)$. But then $(u_n)$ converges also against $u$ in $L^2(M)$ and since $V$ is closed in $L^2$ we have that $u\in V$. Hence $V$ is also closed in $H^m(M)$.