# Determine the precompactness of a set of functions

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

Consider the following operator $T:L^2([0,1]) \rightarrow L^2([0,1])$ given by
$$Tu(x) = \int_{x^2}^{x} u(t) dt$$
They ask me to dermine whether or not the set $T(B_1)$ is precompact (or, equivalently, relatively compact) in $L^2([0,1])$, where $B_1$ denotes the unit ball in $L^2([0,1])$.

Any hint is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator can be written in the form
$$
Tu(x)=\int_0^1 1_{[x^2,x]}(t)u(t)\,\mathrm{d}t,
$$
where $1_{[x^2,x]}(t)$ is the characteristic function. This is a Hilbert-Schmidt integral operator with $K(x,t)=1_{[x^2,x]}(t)\in L^2([0,1]\times[0,1]).$ This operator is compact, meaning the image of bounded sets is precompact. Hence, $T(B_1)$ is precompact.

For more information, perhaps consider [Proof of compactness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1001185/prove-that-this-integral-operator-is-compact). This proof assumes $K$ is continuous, but you may be able to tweak the proof.

Comment: thank you for you answer. If I wanted to prove the compactness of $T$ without using a concept like Hilbert-Schmidt operators, could I still reach the goal? The fact is that I am not suppose to know Hilbert-Schmidt operators, so I wonder if I could still prove the precompactness using only the definition of compact operator or the Kolmogorov criterion.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short direct proof of that the operator $Tu(x)=\int_0^1 1_{[x^2,x]}(t)u(t)\,\mathrm{d}t,$ is compact. We need the following statement: if $e_n(x)$ forms orthonormal basis in $L_2[0,1]$, then $e_n(x)e_m(t)$ forms orthonormal basis in $L_2([0,1]\times[0,1])$. This is a well-known simple statement, but if you wish, you can prove it yourself as an exercise.

Now, consider the generating function $K(x,t)=1_{[x^2,x]}(t)$ of our operator $T$. For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ consider the integral operator $T_n$ with generating function $K_n(x,t)=\sum\limits_{k,l=1}^n c_{k,l}e_k(x)e_l(t)$, where $c_{k,l}=(K,e_k(x)e_l(t))$ are Fourier coefficients of $K$. It's obvious that $T_n$ has a finite rank (it's range are linear combination of functions $e_k(x)$, $k=1,2,...,n$). Hence $T_n$ -- is compact. Further, $T-T_n$ -- is a integral operator with generating function $K-K_n$. By Holder's inequality it's easy to proof that $\|T-T_n\|\leq \|K-K_n\|\to0$ according to the previous statement. Thus $T$ also compact.

Note that it is also possible to proof according to the criterion of precompactness, but it is much longer.